Why is Entropy inversely proportional to Temperature?
I was trying to comprehend the second law of thermodynamics, then I got a doubt:
Why is Entropy(S) inversely proportional to Temperature?
My reasoning for understanding entropy was:
Suppose you take an ideal gas at room temp. Now if I provide it heat or any form of non-conservative work, then the randomness would increase. Since the particles will have to adjust their translational state accordingly, so randomness, or the number of possible microscopic arrangements [I saw this in wiki] will increase.
But when I am providing it heat in non-isothermal conditions, the temperature ought to change. But why would it only decrease and not increase?

As S grows with T, it cannot be inversely proportional. You may confuse it with consequences of the classical TD definition dS = dQ_rev/T. For the given heat, it is the increment of S, not S itself, that is inversely proportional to T.

Before you ask "why", ask "if".

Try not to equate entropy with randomness, it is a measure of randomness and this is a very different thing but confusing as 'measure' usually is usually forgotten about. It is less confusing and better to think of it as the number of ways (arrangements) you can put molecules into a volume or into energy levels etc.

@porphyrin Oh yes, it seems I was confusing it with the classical TD definition of dS.

@IvanNeretin So I'll have to assume the different cases. In my example, dS is proportional to dT But I was thinking about dS being inversely proportional to T.
When is dS inversely proportional to T?
But maybe I misunderstood what you meant by asking "why" before "if"?

For the given $\delta Q$, $\text{d}S \propto \dfrac{1}{T}$

Heat added to a system at a lower temperature causes greater randomness than in comparison to when heat is added to it at a higher temperature.
*Here the main confusion that I have seen my classmates have is between temperature and heat. Heat is a form of energy that flows between two objects with a temperature difference. As such it can do more work when the temp. diff is higher
Coming back to your original analogy, providing heat to gasses that are already colliding a lot will not have the same amount of increase as to make non-colliding gasses collide which will produce a greater change in entropy.
